# How to prevent Windows Home server waking for backup

Tags: windows-home-server

Since changing the motherboard in my Windows home server it has been switching itself on every night to perform a scheduled backup.

I don't want this to happen though, I want to switch the server on using Wake on lan, but I want to manually perform backups if/when required.

I know I can disable backups of each computer, and the machine wont turn on, but I want to allow manually triggered backups, or automatic backups if the homeserver is on, but if its in sleep mode, I wish it to stay in that state unless I wake it.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

First off; It's a pretty good idea to let the server perform the backups, and therefore automatically resume for them.  However, I can understand wanting to save power etc so...

Do you have any further power related addon's installed on you Home Server that may be starting the system?  WHS is primarily designed as an always on device and I didn't think that it initially shipped with an "auto-wake for backup" task running as it wasn't meant to be a common need.  Hence why I'm asking "Is anything else causing your wakeup (Lights-Out maybe?)

If it is by design, then there is no simple way to disable it that I know of, as it can be achieved in a number of ways.  My first place to look would be the "task scheduler" on the home server box. (You'll need to remote terminal in to take a look though)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misting something, but if you right click the WHS icon in one of the client computers there is a check-box which you can uncheck to achieve your goal ("Wake this computer for backup")